# ¿Cómo colocar varios condicionales a un if?

Tags: python, condiciones

es que estoy programando un archivo python con unas formulas para que el usuario ingrese los datos de sus notas y le de el resultado, en mi universidad dividen los 6 meses en 3 periodos o cortes, entonces p1 y p2 son formulas iguales pero para p3 las formulas son muy diferentes, entonces cuando al if le coloco varios condicionales me salta error, vale recalcar que el valor del corte lo ingresa la persona ( es decir: el coloca si es p1 o p2 o p3)

```
import time
print("Programa para sacar notas de p1, p2 o p3")

time.sleep(1)

nombre=input("Escribe tu nombre aqui:  ")
print("Bienvenid@  = " + nombre + " =  para comenzar a calcular")


time.sleep(0)


elegir_corte = int(input("Escribe el corte que vamos a calcular (Ej: 1, 2, 3):  "))


if elegir_corte==1 and elegir_corte ==2:
     print("sdsadas") ...
```

ahí va el resto de código que tengo con formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que usar un or en vez de un and, ya que nunca va a ser las 2 cosas a la vez.

Comment: gracias, lo habia pensado pero no lo habia usado :D gracias bro me ahorraste demasiado codigo que pensaba meter con un elif :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes investigar como funcionan los switch en python, de todos modos te dejo un ejemplo.

**Con los Switch puedes hacer 2 casos o 3 o los que consideres necesarios en donde tienes que hacer uso de un entero el cual según el dato que contenga entrará a su respectivo caso.**

```py
def one():
   return "January"

def two():
   return "February"

def three():
   return "March"

def numbers_to_months(argument):
   switcher = {
       1: one,
       2: two,
       3: three

   }

   func = switcher.get(argument, lambda: "Invalid month")

   print func()
```

Tambien podrias hacerlo de esta forma

```py
      if elegir_corte == p3:
print("El codigo a ejecutar de P3")

else: 

print("codigo a ejecutar de P1 y P2")
```

ya que sabes que tanto P1 y P2  tienen el mismo procedimiento,más bien pregunta si es P3 pues resuelves el codigo a ejecutar y si no es P3 debe ser o P1 o P2 pero eso no importa porque al final tanto P1 como P2 ejecutan el mismo codigo.

Espero te sirva de algo.

Comment: Es que me cree el programa con lo que se hasta el momento, me falta aun aprender bucles, swtich, poo, etc... ojala pudiera compartir el archivo para que lo vieran :D me gusto mucho pero es poco eficiente porque son muchas lineas de codigo para 3 formulas, gracias y probare el codigo que dejaste.

Comment: En Python no existe la estructura switch mi estimado.